# How can one build PyQt6 application for android?

Tags: android, build, pyqt6, qt6

After searching through available documentation, i came to realise that PyQt applications are meant to be deployed via `pyqtdeploy`, but it does not support Qt6 yet. Qt itself has `androiddeployqt` tool, but it works, as far as i can tell, with qmake/cmake projects and not with python applications using pyqt.

Is there such a way?

Comment: PySide6.5 has a preview feature for andriod deployment https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-6.5